# ErlangC Python Function

Tags: python, loops

The objective of this is to increase Variable N by 1 until the result is equal to Variable SLT or just under SLT. I am new at python, but this is what I came up with:

```
from math import factorial
import math

{A = 10

N = 11

TGT = 20

SLT = .80

AHT = 180
}


def ErlangC():

    if (N-A<=0):
        return 1
    else:
        L = (A**N / factorial(N)) * (N / (N - A))
        sum_ = 0
    for i in range(N):
        sum_ += (A**i) / factorial(i)

    return (1 - (L / (sum_ + L)) * math.exp((-(N-A) * (TGT / AHT))))

ErlangC()
```

Comment: I can increase N by 1 by writing out every function. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

the idea behind it is making a while loop until the required service level is achieved, you can use [pyworkforce](https://pypi.org/project/pyworkforce/) which already has this function implemented, example:

Example:

```py
from pyworkforce.queuing import ErlangC

erlang = ErlangC(transactions=100, asa=20/60, aht=3, interval=30, shrinkage=0.3)

positions_requirements = erlang.required_positions(service_level=0.8, max_occupancy=0.85)
print("positions_requirements: ", positions_requirements)
```

Output:

```
>> positions_requirements:  {'raw_positions': 14, 
                             'positions': 20, 
                             'service_level': 0.8883500191794669, 
                             'occupancy': 0.7142857142857143, 
                             'waiting_probability': 0.1741319335950498}
```